# Golang struct for Dynamic json, Returning null value

Tags: json, go, cockroachdb

I try to get dynamic json data from database "cockroach" but I get null value when execute on golang,

Content data type in database is JSONB, **here my golang struct**,

note: value of Content here are Dynamic Json (every content have different json value).

If you have idea about this please let me know thanks.

```
type Result struct {
    Topic       string
    MessageType string
    Sender      string
    Content     interface{}
}
type SubscriberResponse struct {
    Result []*Result
}
```

and here my **golang service**

```
var results []*Result
var subscriberResponse *SubscriberResponse

sql := (`SELECT topic, message_type, sender, content FROM users`)
rs, err := s.db.QueryContext(ctx, sql)
if err == nil {
    for rs.Next() {
        result := &Result{}
        rs.Scan(
            &result.Topic,
            &result.MessageType,
            &result.Sender,
            &result.Content)
        results = append(results, result)
    }
    subscriberResponse = &SubscriberResponse{
        Result: results,
    }
    return subscriberResponse, nil
}
return nil, err
```

and here result of **golang service**

```
{
"Result": [
    {
        "Topic": "a2",
        "MessageType": "b2",
        "Sender": "c2",
        "Content": null
    },
    {
        "Topic": "a3",
        "MessageType": "b3",
        "Sender": "c3",
        "Content": null
    }]
}
```

**here additional info result when execute that query on database**
[databse result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWxBl.png)

**any idea or modification are welcome.**

Comment: You first need to start with not ignoring errors. You also need to close rows after you're done with them, preferably using defer immediately after successfully getting them from Query/QueryContext. Once you've done that, once you've checked the errors and resolved the issues they point to and you're still getting `null` in your json, then come back to SO, update the question with the proper code and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: Also whenever possible try not to post images nor links to images. The db output from the executed query is plain text, perfectly suited to be copied and pasted into the question. See this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) if you need an explanation.

Comment: Is the content column is of JSON type? then You cannot scan into interface{} type.
The content column should be of concrete type. You can use []byte if the fields in the JSON string of the content is unknown. or you can define your own custom struct type
if the fields are known

Comment: I try change type of content to []byte but give same result,

Comment: edited: this problem solve, some how by changing to []byte and add some modification

Comment: @RikiAfifuddin glad you figured it out. Can you write what you did as an answer, and mark this question as resolved?